# URL Schemes not working on macOS

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa, url, oauth

I'm working on an app that needs to get an authorization token from an external provider.
So, I need a custom URL scheme for the redirection callback.

The redirection callback is: `chirper://success`.

I registered the URL Scheme in my `Info.plist`:
[image: URL Scheme]

I also added the following method in my `AppDelegate.swift`:

```
func handleGetURLEvent(event: NSAppleEventDescriptor?, replyEvent: NSAppleEventDescriptor?) {
    if let aeEventDescriptor = event?.paramDescriptor(forKeyword: AEKeyword(keyDirectObject)) {
        if let urlStr = aeEventDescriptor.stringValue {
            let url = URL(string: urlStr)
            print(url)
            // do something with the URL
        }
    }
}
```

But when I open the redirection callback URL with Safari, this is what I get:
[image: Safari]

> *Safari can't open this URL because macOS doesn't recognize URLs that start with `chirper:`*

Comment: is the app running when you click on the link?

Comment: @albert Yes, it's working. But safari can't open the URL

Comment: hmmm. ok, have you followed this? https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/Inter-AppCommunication/Inter-AppCommunication.html

Comment: whoever downvoted this without a comment....i downvote you

Comment: @albert No because this documentation is for iOS right? I'm developing a macOS app

Comment: i apologize...my bad. how about this: https://css-tricks.com/create-url-scheme/

Comment: @albert I’ll test this as soon as possible.

Comment: @albert Doesn't work... But don't worry I have an idea to do it using another method.

Comment: apologies, good luck! share your findings!

Comment: @albert Instead of using URL Schemes, I’ll create a WKWebView and listen for new URLs to get the access token. I couldn’t find any other methods

Comment: once you fix it, you should post it as an answer, then accept it

Comment: @albert The reason why I’m not posting my answer is because I’m abandoning the idea of URL Schemes when I use a WKWebView. But thank you for your help 

Comment: Try to "Clean Build Folder" and rebuild. Did help for me. Looks like this is required in some cases.

Comment: @toma Work for me! Thx!

Comment: @toma Wow - this actually worked.

Answer (score 6):

Try to "Clean Build Folder" and rebuild. Did help for me. Looks like this is required in some cases.

Answer (score 1):

According to the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58223030/aswebauthenticationsession-in-macos-10-15-catalina), the problem is the inclusion of `://` in the callback URL. If you remove those, the URL should be opened. I found this was correct on macOS 10.15.5.