# ASWebAuthenticationSession in MacOS 10.15 (Catalina)

Tags: macos, oauth, macos-catalina, aswebauthenticationsession

I am trying to implement the new `ASWebAuthenticationSession` in MacOS 10.15 and I'm getting a bit confused about the `callbackURLScheme`.

The header file for `ASWebAuthenticationSession` says:

> The callback URL usually has a custom URL scheme. For the app to
>   receive the callback URL, it needs to either register the  custom URL
>   scheme in its Info.plist, or set the scheme to callbackURLScheme
>   argument in the initializer.

So I initialize like this:

```
self.webAuthSession = [[ASWebAuthenticationSession alloc] initWithURL:self.authURL
                                                    callbackURLScheme:@"myurlscheme://"
                                                    completionHandler:^(NSURL * _Nullable callbackURL, NSError * _Nullable error) {

}];
```

The oauth provider I am trying to access, does not support custom URL schemes, so I have it set to redirect to a web address which in turn redirects to my URL Scheme.

So, after clicking Login in my MacOS app, Safari presents a window that allows me to login to the service. After successfully logging in the redirect happens but the web page just goes to a screen saying

> Safari can't open the specified address.

I can see that the address is `myurlscheme://?code=1234567890abcdefgetc...` which is correct but it's obviously not calling the `ASWebAuthenticationSession` callback.

If I add the URL Scheme to the plist, then the safari window shows a prompt asking if you want to open it in the my app.

I know I can then fetch the code from the App Delegate's `application:openURLs:` method, but this is fiddly, has an unnecessary prompt for the user to click, and also leaves the `ASWebAuth...` safari window open. This should all be automatic through the callback.

The only way I get the callback to fire, is by closing the safari window in which case it calls back with error.

Comment: Same for me. Works perfectly on iOS and doesn't work well on MacOS. Still looking for workaround to close Safari after redirect prompt. `session.cancel()` doesn't work for this case.

Comment: I might submit a bug report to Apple. I think you should do the same.

Comment: Sure, will do it on next Monday

Answer (score 4):

I have just returned to this to try again and it seems to be working fine on MacOS `10.15.1` and `10.15.2 beta`.

I have noticed that the `callbackURLScheme` parameter must not include `://`

I'm not able to go back and test it again on `10.15` but i'm happy to use this now assuming everyone on `10.15` would have updated to `10.15.1`

Answer (score 0):

Darren is right in MacOS you must remove the :// from the callbackURLScheme. iOS works fine no matter if you :// or not. However, in MacOS Catalyst there seems to be a bug. My app is getting focused once I login, but isn't getting the callback. Haven't found a way to fix it yet.